# How make search bar bigger?

Tags: html, css

I'm try to get the search box bigger. Can anyone help me with this?

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <form class="google-search" action="https://www.google.nl/search" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Google Search" maxlength="2085">
        <span class="google-search-btn">
      <input class="google-search-btn" type="submit" value="Search">
     </span>
      </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) ! What do you mean by bigger? More width, more height, change the look of it entirely? Please elaborate a bit for us (by editing the question) to help you out here. Also the minimum amount of characters is there for a reason and trying to get around it by spamming is not the way to go.

Comment: @Maharkus more height, but i already this problem with styling.css

Answer (score 0):

In your styling you will want too set the width like this:

`.google-search input{
width:100px
}`